# could not understand this property of the auxiliary equation,please help.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am staring at the yellow highlighted part and got stuck. Would anyone tell me what algebraic property would make ar^2+br+c=0 in the second term because r is a root? please see the images for detail.

[image]

Comment: The only solution of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ when $b^2-4ac=0$ is $x=-b/2a.$

Comment: I still don't understand why this fact makes  ax2+bx+c=0 @mfl

Comment: "I still don't understand why this fact makes ax2+bx+c=0" Nobody says that ax2+bx+c=0 but that ar2+br+c=0 (which should be obvious since *this is the way r is defined*).